# Just How Independent are Events Anyways

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, naive-bayes

I want to describe a thought experiment to explore independent events, and whether they may actually be linked.

> You are given a set of **independent** coin generators.
> Coin generators are true random number generators that return 'Heads' or 'Tails'.
> The probability that any of the **independent** coin generators would return heads is $0.5$.
> The set of all of these coin generators is $S$.
> $\# S = n$.
> You fire all the coin generators, and they all produce their results.
> Before observing the coin generators, you split the coin generators into two groups $A$ and $B$.
> The selection of each group is random.
> $\# A + \# B = n$
> You get two pieces of paper and write out your expectation for the number of heads you expect for each group on each piece.
> You then observe $A$.
> Do you change your observation for $B$?
> Should you?

The random variables of interest are ${\#}h(A)$ and ${\#}h(B)$.

A few things I feel need to be made explicit. As at the time you conducted the experiment (immediately after firing the coin generators and before splitting $S$), the number of heads in $S$ was fixed. Let's call the set of all heads in $S$ $H$.
For each $V \subset S$ the set of all heads in $V$ is $h(V)$.
 
The selection process is random, this means that $\frac{{\#}A}{{\#}S} : \frac{{\#}h(A)}{{\#}H}$ may be $\gt 1, \, \lt 1$ or $= 1$. However, for each $A$ and $S$, only a few selections ($n\choose {\#}A$) produce $\frac{{\#}A}{{\#}S} : \frac{{\#}h(A)}{{\#}H} = 1$.

$A = B'$ and vice versa.
 
Let's call the sampling from $S$ such that $\frac{{\#}A}{{\#}S} = \frac{{\#}h(A)}{{\#}H}$ the equal sampling $(T_E)$.
Let's call the sampling from $S$ such that $\frac{{\#}A}{{\#}S} \gt \frac{{\#}h(A)}{{\#}H}$ the $A$-biased sampling $(T_A)$.
Let's call the sampling from $S$ such that $\frac{{\#}A}{{\#}S} \lt \frac{{\#}h(A)}{{\#}H}$ the $B$-biased sampling $(T_B)$.
 
$Pr(T_E) = n{\choose}{\#}A$
$$Pr(T_A) = Pr(T_B) = \frac{2^n - {{n}\choose{\#}A}}{2}$$

I feel the above should be kept in mind when we consider whether $h(A)$ affects $E\left(h(B)\right)$. For one, observing a higher than expected amount of heads in $A$ may raise the probability of the $A$-biased sampling.
 
I think that depending on what I observed in $A$, that I may revise my beliefs about $B$. Assuming $n = 8$, ${\#}A = 6$, and $h(A) = 6$, I will update (an increase) my posterior probability on the selection chosen favouring $A$ over $B$ in distribution of heads. This may in turn lead me to lower my estimation of the heads contained in $B$.

I think my stance of possibly shifting my beliefs about $B$ based on my observation of $A$ is legitimate, as the selection process is random and may lead to an unfair distribution of heads.

Should we shift our beliefs after observing $A$ (and more importantly, why so)?

## NOTE:

I think it is important to draw a distinction between this experiment and the gambler's fallacy. We do not first generate $A$ and then subsequently generate $B$ (in which case $h(A)$ would be independent of $h(B)$), we generate $S$. We do not observe the number of heads or tails in $S$. The coin generators may be fired in any order (temporal or otherwise), but we do not observe $S$ until after all $x \in S$ have finished generating.
 
We then randomly sample $S$ into $A$ and $B(A')$. After sampling $S$, we estimate the number of heads in $A$ and $B$ $\left(E\left(h(A)\right) \text{and} \, E\left(h(B)\right) \text{respectively}\right)$. After our estimation, we observe $A$: should we update $E\left(h(A)\right)$ in light of $h(A)$? I don't think it's as clear cut as people seem to be making it out to be.

Comment: You seem to be confounding a simple problem of probability, hinging on the definition of independence (as stated in the first half of the this question) with a statistical problem of estimating the underlying Bernoulli parameter (which is a non-problem, because you have asserted the value of that parameter is $1/2$).  This silent, implicit change in the question underlies the confusion displayed in the second half.  Which question do you really want to address: the one you have stated or the one you appear to be solving?

Answer (score 1):

Since you know, *a priori*, that the outcome of each generator is iid Bernoulli(0.5), then there is no basis for you to update your estimate of $E[h(A)]$ or $E[h(B)]$. The reason is that you didn't say you know the total number of heads (#$H$), so observing $A$ doesn't constrain what $B$ could be.

The reason is that the outcomes from each generator are [exchangeable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables), and so knowledge of one partition doesn't help you in understanding the other partition.

The issue of *when* the generators were fired is irrelevant, the basic theory is that, by the iid assumption, $P(S_1,S_2|S_3,S_4,...,S_n) = P(S_1,S_2)$, so your expected value calculations shouldn't change.

So what could be conditional?

Say you know $h(A) + h(B) = N$, then, even if the generators are independent, you know $h(A)$ you know that $E[h(B)] = N - h(A)$.

Another case is if we drop the constraint $h(A) + h(B) = N$, we still have $E[h(S)|h(A)] = h(A) + \frac{\#B}{2}$

That's one way you would get conditional expectation to differ from unconditional even in the case of independence...but it requires altering the sample space to reflect new knowledge.

Your derivations of $A-$biased, $B$-biased are only relevant if you know $N$...if you don't then its not relevant.

### ## R Code Example ##

Let's simulate this process to show what it looks like:

```
h_A <- c()
h_B <- c()
n_A <- c()
n_B <- c()

for(i in 1:1000){
  S <- rbinom(10,1,0.5) #fire generators
  idx_A <- sample(1:length(S),round(runif(1,0,length(S))),replace = FALSE) #select A
  A <- S[idx_A] #assign values for A
  B <- S[setdiff((1:10),idx_A)] #assign rest to B
  h_A <- append(h_A,sum(A))
  n_A <- append(n_A,length(A))
  n_B <- append(n_B,length(B))
  h_B <- append(h_B,sum(B))
}

plot(h_A,h_B)

#look at conditional means
A_values <- unique(h_A)
uncond_mean <- c()
cond_mean <- c()

for(i in 1:length(A_values)){
  val <- A_values[i]
  subset_A <- h_A==val #where did we see h_A == val
  n <- n_B[subset_A] #size of B partition
  selected_B <- h_B[subset_A] #what was the number of heads in B?
  uncond_mean <- append(uncond_mean,mean(n/2)) #just find mean of 10-N independent tosses
  cond_mean <- append(cond_mean,mean(selected_B)) #actually calculate mean of B
}

plot(uncond_mean,cond_mean)

lm(cond_mean ~ uncond_mean)
```

You get as output:

[image: joint distribution of (h(A),h(B))]

Now, look at conditional vs unconditional means:
[image]

```
Call:
lm(formula = cond_mean ~ uncond_mean)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  uncond_mean  
    0.01645      0.98479
```

So, the actual heads tracks the *unconditional mean*

Comment: I have edited the question to be more relevant. Please re-read it. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: @TobiAlafin ok, so you're dealing with the true iid case with known parameters. See my revised explanation.

Comment: What is iid? $N$ is the number of elements in $S$, so you always no $N$. Could you be referring to some other variable.

Comment: @TobiAlafin iid = independent, identically distributed (all variables have same distribution and are independent ). N is the total number of heads (I guess I should have said $\#H$ to use your notation)